# XML data into data.frame table

Tags: r, xml

I have this code:

```
# Downloading data from IMF via JSON
u.xml <- "http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_XML.svc/CompactData/IFS/Q..BFDA_BP6_USD.?startPeriod=2000&endPeriod=2022"
## parse the xml document and get the top-level XML node
doc <- xmlParse(u.xml)
top <- xmlRoot(doc)
```

Now, my question is how to turn `top` into a data.frame table? Thank you very much!

P.S. Desired data.frame table looks like this:

```
  FREQ REF_AREA INDICATOR      UNIT_MULT  TIME_FORMAT  TIME_PERIOD OBS_VALUE
1 Q    BS       BFDA_BP6_USD   6          P3M          2000-Q1     0
2 Q    BS       BFDA_BP6_USD   6          P3M          2000-Q2     0
...
```

Comment: What do you mean *top level*? Please post sample of XML and desired output in body of question since links can change.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need all `Series` nodes and given XML is atteibute-centric, consider the undocumented method, **`xmlAttrsToDataFrame`**. However, be sure to assign a prefix for the default namespace in parent tag `DataSet` in order to run XPath on `Series` elements:

```r
nmsp <- c(data = "http://dataservices.imf.org/compact/IFS") 

imf_series_df <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(
    getNodeSet(doc, path="//data:Series", namespaces=nmsp)
)
```